# No matching function for call to?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm getting the error "no matching function for call to readProgrammers" how can I fix this?

 
this is the main.cpp file I also have a .h file the declares all the functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "programmer.h"

using namespace std;

const int MAX_PROGRAMMERS = 10;

int main()
{
    Programmer programmers[MAX_PROGRAMMERS];
    int numProgrammers = 0;
   
    ifstream inputFile( "programmers.txt" ); // declares file stream and opens for input
  
    if( inputFile.good() )
    {
        numProgrammers = readProgrammers( inputFile, programmers, MAX_PROGRAMMERS );
      
        //close the input file because we are done with it
        inputFile.close();
      
        //report on programmers to console
        generateProgrammerReport( cout, programmers, numProgrammers ); // cout passed as an ostream
      
        //report on programmers to a file
        ofstream outputFile("ProgrammerReport.txt");
        generateProgrammerReport( outputFile, programmers, numProgrammers );
        outputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File not opened properly!!\n\n";
    }
   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
   
}
```

this is the programmer.cpp file. This is the file that has the error in the generateProgrammerInfo function when I am trying to call the function readProgrammers.

```
#include "programmer.h"
#include "sstream"
#include "iomanip"

//implement functions here!

//returns the number of programmers - fills in the programmers array from the ifstream
int readProgrammers( ifstream& inputFile, Programmer programmers[], int maxProgrammers )
{
  int numProgrammers = 0;
  int programmer_id;
  string name;
  int lines;
  if(inputFile.is_open())
  {
    while (!inputFile.eof() && numProgrammers < maxProgrammers)
    {
      inputFile >> programmers[numProgrammers].programmer_id;
      inputFile >> programmers[numProgrammers].name;
      inputFile >> programmers[numProgrammers].lines;
      numProgrammers++;
    }
  }
    //just a stub!
    return numProgrammers;
}

//returns the total of the lines field for all programmers
int calcTotalLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
  int totalLine = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; i++)
  {
    totalLine += programmers[i].lines; 
  }
  
    //just a stub!
    return totalLine;
}

//returns the average lines coded for all programmers as a float
float calcAverageLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
  int totalLine = calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
  int averageLines = 0;
  averageLines = totalLine/numProgrammers;
    //just a stub!
    return averageLines;
}
//return a string containing info for a particular programmer
string generateProgrammerInfo( Programmer theProgrammer )
{
  ifstream inputFile;
  Programmer programmers;
  int MAX_PROGRAMMERS;
  readProgrammers( inputFile, programmers, MAX_PROGRAMMERS );
  int numProgrammers;
  int programmer_id;
  string name;
  int lines;
  const int SPACING = 5;
  stringstream sout;
  sout << setw(SPACING) << theProgrammer.programmer_id << " " << theProgrammer.name << " " << theProgrammer.lines << endl;
    //just a stub!
    return sout.str();
}

//generate report for all programmers
//call calcTotalLines, calcAverageLines, and generateProgrammerInfo functions
void generateProgrammerReport( ostream& output, Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
  Programmer theProgrammer;
  generateProgrammerInfo(theProgrammer);
  calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
  calcAverageLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
    //just a stub!
    output << "These are all the programmers:" << endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; i++ )
    {
        output << generateProgrammerInfo(theProgrammer); //this should output the programmer info for each programmer
    }
    output << "\nTotal lines = " << calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers); //this should ouptut the total lines
    output << "\nAverage lines = " << calcAverageLines(programmers, numProgrammers); //this should output the average lines
    output << endl;
}
```

This is the programmer.h file

```
#ifndef __lab2__programmer__
#define __lab2__programmer__

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Programmer
{
    int programmer_id;
    string name;
    int lines; // lines of code programmed
};

//function prototypes

//returns the number of programmers - fills in the programmers array from the ifstream
int readProgrammers( ifstream& inputFile, Programmer programmers[], int maxProgrammers );

//returns the total of the lines field for all programmers
int calcTotalLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers );

//returns the average lines coded for all programmers as a float
float calcAverageLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers );

//return a string containing info for a particular programmer
string generateProgrammerInfo( Programmer theProgrammer );

//generate report for all employees
void generateProgrammerReport( ostream& output, Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers );


#endif /* defined(__lab2__programmer__) */
```

I can't change the main.cpp file or the programmer.h file.

Comment: yes it is declared

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9Td8xKbej), please show a [mre] including the full error message from the compiler

Comment: The error message most likely continues with a list of the candidates the compiler has indentified. What are they?

Comment: also note that identifiers starting with 2 underscores are reserved for use by the compiler. `using namespace std` [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and should never be used in a header file

Comment: all the error message says is "no matching function for call to readProgrammers". I think that I'm calling the function wrong or something but I'm not sure.

Comment: That’s guaranteed to not be all the error message says.

Comment: Do you have to use C-style arrays? Otherwise consider using `std::array`

Comment: it also says "Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Programmer' to 'Programmer *' for 2nd argument; take the address of the argument with &"

Comment: OK, this is why we ask for a [mre], `main.cpp` is not relevant to the question and could be omitted. In `generateProgrammerInfo` you are doing `readProgrammers( inputFile, programmers, MAX_PROGRAMMERS );` but `programmers` is an object not an array so doesn't match the function arguments, the error message seems fairly self explanatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `generateProgrammerInfo()`, this code is wrong:

```
ifstream inputFile;
Programmer programmers;
int MAX_PROGRAMMERS;
readProgrammers( inputFile, programmers, MAX_PROGRAMMERS );
```

First off, `inputFile` in a local variable that does not have a file opened, so there is nothing for `readProgrammers()` to read.  But more importantly, `readProgrammers()` expects a pointer to an array of `Programmer` objects, but you are passing in a single `Programmer` object.  That is why the compiler is complaining that it can't convert a `Programmer` to a `Programmer*`.  Also, `readProgrammers()` expects the number of `Programmer` objects in the array, but `MAX_PROGRAMMERS` is an *uninitialized* local variable.

If your goal were to read in a single `Programmer` object, then you can use this:

```
string generateProgrammerInfo( Programmer &theProgrammer )
{
  ...
  readProgrammers( inputFile, &theProgrammer, 1 );
  ...
}
```

However, given how `generateProgrammerInfo()` is being used inside of `generateProgrammerReport()`, this wold still be wrong.  `generateProgrammerInfo()` should not be trying to read in anything at all, only output things.  And `generateProgrammerReport()` is coded wrong, too.  It is taking in an array of `Programmer`  objects, but is not printing any of them out, it is instead trying to read into a local `Programmer` variable and then printing that out instead.

There are many other issues with your code, too.

- using `""` instead of `<>` for standard headers
- [using `!eof()` in a loop incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/).
- `calcAverageLines()` performing integer division instead of floating-point division.
- `generateProgrammerReport()` calling `calcTotalLines()` and `calcAverageLines()` redundantly.

With that said, try this instead:

```
#include "programmer.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

//returns the number of programmers - fills in the programmers array from the ifstream
int readProgrammers( ifstream& inputFile, Programmer programmers[], int maxProgrammers )
{
    int numProgrammers = 0;
    int programmer_id;
    string name;
    int lines;
    while ((numProgrammers < maxProgrammers)
        && (inputFile >> programmer_id)
        && (inputFile >> name)
        && (inputFile >> lines)
    {
        programmers[numProgrammers].programmer_id = programmer_id;
        programmers[numProgrammers].name = name;
        programmers[numProgrammers].lines = lines;
        ++numProgrammers;
    }
    return numProgrammers;
}

//returns the total of the lines field for all programmers
int calcTotalLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
    int totalLine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; ++i)
    {
        totalLine += programmers[i].lines; 
    }
    return totalLine;
}

//returns the average lines coded for all programmers as a float
float calcAverageLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
    float totalLine = calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
    return totalLine / numProgrammers;
}

//return a string containing info for a particular programmer
string generateProgrammerInfo( Programmer theProgrammer )
{
    const int SPACING = 5;
    stringstream sout;
    sout << setw(SPACING) << theProgrammer.programmer_id << " " << theProgrammer.name << " " << theProgrammer.lines << endl;
    return sout.str();
}

//generate report for all programmers
//call calcTotalLines, calcAverageLines, and generateProgrammerInfo functions
void generateProgrammerReport( ostream& output, Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
    output << "These are all the programmers:" << endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; ++i )
    {
        output << generateProgrammerInfo( programmers[i] ); //this should output the programmer info for each programmer
    }
    output << "\nTotal lines = " << calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers); //this should output the total lines
    output << "\nAverage lines = " << calcAverageLines(programmers, numProgrammers); //this should output the average lines
    output << endl;
}
```